# Are Convex Linear Functions of Density Matrices Actually Linear Functions?

Tags: linear-transformations, quantum-computation, quantum-information

I feel like I often see passing comments about this without proof in quantum info literature, but I wasn't able to show it myself! For instance p17/p18 of [this classic](http://theory.caltech.edu/%7Epreskill/ph219/chap3_15.pdf)

Lets say that we have some function $f : L_1 (H) \rightarrow L_1(H)$ on the space $L_1(H)$ of trace 1 density matrices on a finite dimensional complex Hilbert space. Lets say that I know that for any $p \in [0,1]$ then $f(p\rho + (1-p)\sigma) = p f(\rho) + (1-p)f(\sigma)$:

Does it follow that $f(a \rho + b \sigma) = af(\rho) + bf(\sigma)$ for any complex $a,b$?

If not, what if $f$ also preserves pure states, meaning there exists some function $f':H \rightarrow H$ such that for each $\psi$ then $f(|\psi\rangle \langle \psi|) = |f'(\psi)\rangle \langle f'(\psi)|$?

Comment: Strictly speaking, it does not follow. If all that we require of our function is that it preserves convex combinations on density matrices, this does not say anything about how that mapping acts on non-density matrices. However, a mapping that preserves convex combinations of density matrices does extend *uniquely* to a linear map on the space of all matrices. For convenience, it is useful to deal with a linear map.

Comment: Extending upon @Luftbahnfahrer's comment, the reason one can always extend a convex-linear map on the states to a linear map on all matrices is the fact every matrix can be written as the linear combination of four states: first decompose $A=\frac12(A+A^*)+i\cdot(-\frac{i}2(A-A^*))$ into Hermitian matrices, then use that—by the spectral theorem—every Hermitian matrix can be decomposed into states via $H={\rm tr}(H_+)\frac{H_+}{{\rm tr}(H_+)}-{\rm tr}(H_-)\frac{H_-}{{\rm tr}(H_-)}$ with $H_+,H_-\geq 0$.